# Fseek a txt to print by character using fgetc

Tags: c, printf, fseek, fgetc

```
fseek(exsist, start, end);
    while(count < end)
    {
        if(feof(exsist)) break;
        c = fgetc(exsist);
        printf("%c",c);
        if(feof(exsist)) break;
        ++count;
```

In theory I feel like this should print character by character until either eof or the intended end. Yet I am getting nothing printed to the terminal. I have been opening the file because I have a check above if it doesn’t see it.

Comment: Please provide us with an [mre]. What is `start`? What is `end`? What is `count`?

Comment: We can only guess that `end` is the same as `SEEK_END` etc.

Comment: Add fflush(stdout) right after the printf() as you don't put '\n', the output buffer is not fllushed.

Comment: What happens if you get a read error?

Comment: Exsist is a open file. Start is an int from user of the character to start at. End is an int from the user to stop at. Count is a ticker incriminating after each loop. @RefugnicEternium besides this code there is a check for file fopen ==NULL. William there wasn’t a read error in this code. Thank y’all for the help. I will try the fflush rachid k